# Got GRUB minimal BASH-like instead of full GRUB

Tags: linux, debian, grub2, grub, uefi

Installed PureOS, it is Debian GNU/Linux testing based distribution. (They are almost identical, read on that I just have Debian.) The problem is that the system can be installed only with this partitioning:

Disklabel type: **DOS**

1. Partition ext4 /boot
2. Partition ext4 /
3. Partition swap

Legacy BIOS, apt package grub-pc.

I want another configuration:

Disklabel type: **GPT**

1. Partition vfat /efi
2. Partition LVM with logical volumes: /, /boot, /home, /var, swap

UEFI, apt package grub-efi.

After the installation, I rebooted into the Live CD again. Copyied all the data from hard drive to USB Flash. Manually did repartitioning. Then copyied data from USB Flash to disk back. Fixed /etc/fstab. Now have to install the GRUB.

I made:

```
# /dev/nvme0n1p1
mount /dev/nvme0n1p1 /mnt/efi/

# /dev/nvme0n1p2
mount /dev/vg/lv_root /mnt/
mount /dev/vg/lv_boot /mnt/boot/
mount /dev/vg/lv_home /mnt/home/
mount /dev/vg/lv_var /mnt/var/

mount -t proc proc /mnt/proc/
mount -t sysfs /mnt/sys/
mount -o bind /dev/ /mnt/dev/
mount -o bind /dev/shm/ /mnt/dev/shm/
mount -o bind /dev/pts/ /mnt/dev/pts/
mount -o bind /tmp/ /mnt/tmp/
mount -o bind /run/ /mnt/run/ # For the LVM working in chroot correctly

chroot /mnt/
apt purge grub-pc
apt install grub-efi
grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=/efi/ --bootloader-id=BOOT --boot-directory=/efi/EFI/
update-grub
```

Everything was installed and configured without errors. But after the reboot, I get into GRUB minimal instead of a full GRUB with a OS choice.

What I did wrong?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/376470/how-to-reinstall-grub2-efi

Comment: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=244131